# WPF string animation using StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames: last DiscreteStringKeyFrame not executed

Tags: wpf, animation

I want to animate the text of a textbox using `StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames` and `DiscreteStringKeyFrame`

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtStateRunning" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   <TextBlock.Triggers>
         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
             <BeginStoryboard>
                 <Storyboard x:Name="textAnimation">
                     <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="txtStateRunning" 
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="False" >
                         <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Running ."   KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                         <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Running .."  KeyTime="0:0:0.5" />
                         <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Running ..." KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                         <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Running ...." KeyTime="0:0:1.5" />
                     </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                 </Storyboard>
             </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBlock.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
```

In the code I have 4 * `DiscreteStringKeyFrame` but actually I see only 3 * running. The `DiscreteStringKeyFrame` at time 1.5 is not executed. What I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is happening because your last frame begining to show and instantly replacing by first frame.

You can fix it by adding one more DiscreteStringKeyFrame at the end:

```
<DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
```

Or by setting `Duration` for StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames:

```
<StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:2" ...
```

Comment: Thans, I like the solution with Duration=. Anyway I still do not undestand why the last DiscreteStringKeyFrame is never executed

Comment: As I said because it have no time to show. Your animation length is not specified - then it runs as long as it needs - exactly 1.5 sec. So your last frame being shown for 0 sec - it is instantly replacing by your first frame