# How to change button text and color on mouse enter using WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm new to WPF. I want to change button text and color on `MouseEnter`.
Here is my codes in order to change the color:

```
<Style x:Key="btnClose" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Name="btnClose">
                <Border Name="btnCloseBorder" CornerRadius="7" Background="Red" BorderBrush="#ccc" BorderThickness="0,1,1,0" >
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Button.Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ContentElement ???/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation From="Red" To="#FF7F7F" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="btnCloseBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation From="#FF7F7F" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="btnCloseBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Button Style="{StaticResource btnClose}" Name="btnClose" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="274,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="18" Height="21"/>
```

It works like a charm. But I couldn't change the text.

I guest it should be after `ColorAnimation` tag. But I dont know what tag should be used.

How can I change button text in `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`?

Comment: Set `Button.Content`

Comment: You need a KeyFrameAnimation

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer. I simply removed `Content` in `Button` tag and changed `Style` like below:

```
<Style x:Key="btnClose" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Name="btnClose">
                <Border Name="btnCloseBorder" CornerRadius="7" Background="Red" BorderBrush="#ccc" BorderThickness="0,1,1,0" >
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Button.Content" Value="Your Text">
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard >
                                <ColorAnimation From="Red" To="#FF7F7F" Duration="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetName="btnCloseBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation From="#FF7F7F" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="btnCloseBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property = "Button.Content" Value="Some new text..."/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>

<Button Style="{StaticResource btnClose}" Name="btnClose" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="274,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="18" Height="21"/>
```

I hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly create a ContentControl. You can set `Button.Content` to any object you want. If the object is not a `UIElement`, an implicit `TextBlock` will be created and it's Text set to `Value.ToString()`. If it is a `UIElement`, it's `OnRender` method will be used to render it.

So in your case, you can simply set the setter value to a string.

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Button.Content" Value="Your Text">
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Note that this trigger will automatically revert back to the previous value when `IsMouseOver` becomes false.

Comment: I added your code between`<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` and `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">`. But it does not work. Is it the true place?

Comment: Why do you want an event trigger? A simple trigger will work fine.

Comment: Because I want to change color and text with animation. Do you know any better approach?

Comment: Use KeyFrame animation... See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137625/wpf-string-animation-using-stringanimationusingkeyframes-last-discretestringkey) question for an example.